Point cloud classification exporting trouble

How can I export a single classification of point clouds?
In this instance I have imported some point clouds, merged the tiles then thinned the points. This has created a new layer on which I deselected all the classifications apart from 'buildings'. I want to export just this classification but when I right click and export the layer, the points in every classification get exported.
When exporting the layer, the 'select fields to export' button is greyed out. That seems like the solution but unsure why it is greyed out. I also tried the exporting selected method however the selection tool is greyed out for this layer so I can't select anything.
